# integration: Selected file upload from Google drive (OAuth 2.0 client IDs) to salesforce records notes and attachment

Tags: integration

I have below requirement for Google drive integration(OAuth 2.0 client IDs) with salesforce.

1.Using site,When end user will Create new contact with all required information and when he click on save button he will redirect to Saved contact Detail page and on this page there is one Option to choose the File from google drive. While choosing the file google drive page will pop-up a window for authenticaion. Once authenticaion is done selected file should be saved in that contact notes and attachment related list.

2)Query: After authentication,I am redirect to Authenticated google drive page. currently I am facing issue is after auther authentication it is redirected to vf page.Please find the attchments enter image description here[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Authorized redirect URIs as stated in the explanation from your screenshot is used to redirect your users after they successfully completed their authentication with Google. In your case I assume it should be a simple Visualforce Page (for example, https://.visual.force.com/google/auth/callback). For testing it can be, basically, any string that follows the URI format.

Then you need to create this page and its controller in Salesforce. When Google redirects your users to this uri it will append an access_token parameter, which you should use to get a token.

I suggest that you get familiar with OAuth protocol and its common flows.

[OAuth Community Site](https://oauth.net/) - Basic & Advanced description

[Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=0) - useful for general undertanding